# Compiling PHP from source fails on Mac high sierra

Tags: macos, compilation, installation, macos-sierra

source code: php-7.2.4
Mac high sierra 10.13.4

```
 ./configure 
'--prefix=/Users/weizhao/lnmp/php-7.2.4' 
'--with-fpm-user=weizhao' 
'--with-fpm-group=weizhao' 
'--with-config-file-path=/Users/weizhao/lnmp/php-7.2.4/etc/php.ini' 
'--with-config-file-scan-dir=/Users/weizhao/lnmp/php-7.2.4/etc' 
'--with-pdo-mysql=/Users/weizhao/lnmp/mysql-5.7.9' 
'--with-mysql-sock=/tmp/mysqld.sock' 
'--with-curl' 
'--with-pear' 
'--with-gd' 
'--with-jpeg-dir' 
'--with-png-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.34' 
'--with-zlib' 
'--with-freetype-dir' 
'--with-mcrypt' 
'--with-mhash' 
'--with-mysqli' 
'--enable-pdo' 
'--with-openssl' 
'--with-xmlrpc' 
'--with-xsl' 
'--with-gettext' 
'--enable-bcmath' 
'--enable-fpm' 
'--enable-opcache' 
'--enable-shmop' 
'--enable-soap' 
'--enable-sockets' 
'--enable-wddx' 
'--enable-mbstring' 
'--enable-gd-native-ttf' 
'--enable-exif' 
'--with-iconv' 
'--with-libzip'
```

and the result output :

```
cc -I/usr/include -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -DZEND_SIGNALS   -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/lib -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.34/lib -L/usr/local/opt/freetype/lib -L/Users/weizhao/lnmp/mysql-5.7.9/lib  -Wl,-rpath,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/ssl/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.34/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/freetype/lib -Wl,-rpath,/Users/weizhao/lnmp/mysql-5.7.9/lib ext/date/php_date.o ext/date/lib/astro.o ext/date/lib/dow.o ext/date/lib/parse_date.o ext/date/lib/parse_tz.o ext/date/lib/timelib.o ext/date/lib/tm2unixtime.o ext/date/lib/unixtime2tm.o ext/date/lib/parse_iso_intervals.o ext/date/lib/interval.o ext/libxml/libxml.o ext/openssl/openssl.o ext/openssl/xp_ssl.o ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_chartables.o ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_ucd.o ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_compile.o ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_config.o ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_exec.o ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_fullinfo.o ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_get.o ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_globals.o ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_maketables.o ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_newline.o ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_ord2utf8.o ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_refcount.o ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_study.o ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_tables.o ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_valid_utf8.o ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_version.o ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_xclass.o ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_jit_compile.o ext/pcre/php_pcre.o ext/sqlite3/sqlite3.o ext/sqlite3/libsqlite/sqlite3.o ext/zlib/zlib.o ext/zlib/zlib_fopen_wrapper.o ext/zlib/zlib_filter.o ext/bcmath/bcmath.o ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/add.o ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/div.o ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/init.o ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/neg.o ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/outofmem.o ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/raisemod.o ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/rt.o ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/sub.o ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/compare.o ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/divmod.o ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/int2num.o ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/num2long.o ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/output.o ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/recmul.o ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/sqrt.o ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/zero.o ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/debug.o ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/doaddsub.o ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/nearzero.o ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/num2str.o ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/raise.o ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/rmzero.o ext/bcmath/libbcmath/src/str2num.o ext/ctype/ctype.o ext/curl/interface.o ext/curl/multi.o ext/curl/share.o ext/curl/curl_file.o ext/dom/php_dom.o ext/dom/attr.o ext/dom/document.o ext/dom/domerrorhandler.o ext/dom/domstringlist.o ext/dom/domexception.o ext/dom/namelist.o ext/dom/processinginstruction.o ext/dom/cdatasection.o ext/dom/documentfragment.o ext/dom/domimplementation.o ext/dom/element.o ext/dom/node.o ext/dom/string_extend.o ext/dom/characterdata.o ext/dom/documenttype.o ext/dom/domimplementationlist.o ext/dom/entity.o ext/dom/nodelist.o ext/dom/text.o ext/dom/comment.o ext/dom/domconfiguration.o ext/dom/domimplementationsource.o ext/dom/entityreference.o ext/dom/notation.o ext/dom/xpath.o ext/dom/dom_iterators.o ext/dom/typeinfo.o ext/dom/domerror.o ext/dom/domlocator.o ext/dom/namednodemap.o ext/dom/userdatahandler.o ext/exif/exif.o ext/fileinfo/fileinfo.o ext/fileinfo/libmagic/apprentice.o ext/fileinfo/libmagic/apptype.o ext/fileinfo/libmagic/ascmagic.o ext/fileinfo/libmagic/cdf.o ext/fileinfo/libmagic/cdf_time.o ext/fileinfo/libmagic/compress.o ext/fileinfo/libmagic/encoding.o ext/fileinfo/libmagic/fsmagic.o ext/fileinfo/libmagic/funcs.o ext/fileinfo/libmagic/is_tar.o ext/fileinfo/libmagic/magic.o ext/fileinfo/libmagic/print.o ext/fileinfo/libmagic/readcdf.o ext/fileinfo/libmagic/softmagic.o ext/fileinfo/libmagic/der.o ext/filter/filter.o ext/filter/sanitizing_filters.o ext/filter/logical_filters.o ext/filter/callback_filter.o ext/gd/gd.o ext/gd/libgd/gd.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_gd.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_gd2.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_io.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_io_dp.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_io_file.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_ss.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_io_ss.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_webp.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_png.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_jpeg.o ext/gd/libgd/gdxpm.o ext/gd/libgd/gdfontt.o ext/gd/libgd/gdfonts.o ext/gd/libgd/gdfontmb.o ext/gd/libgd/gdfontl.o ext/gd/libgd/gdfontg.o ext/gd/libgd/gdtables.o ext/gd/libgd/gdft.o ext/gd/libgd/gdcache.o ext/gd/libgd/gdkanji.o ext/gd/libgd/wbmp.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_wbmp.o ext/gd/libgd/gdhelpers.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_topal.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_gif_in.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_xbm.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_gif_out.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_security.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_filter.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_pixelate.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_rotate.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_color_match.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_transform.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_crop.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_interpolation.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_matrix.o ext/gd/libgd/gd_bmp.o ext/gettext/gettext.o ext/hash/hash.o ext/hash/hash_md.o ext/hash/hash_sha.o ext/hash/hash_ripemd.o ext/hash/hash_haval.o ext/hash/hash_tiger.o ext/hash/hash_gost.o ext/hash/hash_snefru.o ext/hash/hash_whirlpool.o ext/hash/hash_adler32.o ext/hash/hash_crc32.o ext/hash/hash_fnv.o ext/hash/hash_joaat.o ext/hash/sha3/generic64lc/KeccakP-1600-opt64.o ext/hash/sha3/generic64lc/KeccakHash.o ext/hash/sha3/generic64lc/KeccakSponge.o ext/hash/hash_sha3.o ext/iconv/iconv.o ext/json/json.o ext/json/json_encoder.o ext/json/json_parser.o ext/json/json_scanner.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/ascii.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/big5.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/cp1251.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/euc_jp.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/euc_jp_prop.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/euc_kr.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/euc_tw.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/gb18030.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/iso8859_1.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/iso8859_10.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/iso8859_11.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/iso8859_13.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/iso8859_14.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/iso8859_15.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/iso8859_16.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/iso8859_2.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/iso8859_3.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/iso8859_4.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/iso8859_5.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/iso8859_6.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/iso8859_7.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/iso8859_8.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/iso8859_9.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/koi8.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/koi8_r.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/onig_init.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/regcomp.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/regenc.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/regerror.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/regexec.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/regext.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/reggnu.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/regparse.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/regposerr.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/regposix.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/regsyntax.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/regtrav.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/regversion.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/sjis.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/sjis_prop.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/st.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/unicode.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/unicode_fold1_key.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/unicode_fold2_key.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/unicode_fold3_key.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/unicode_unfold_key.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/utf16_be.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/utf16_le.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/utf32_be.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/utf32_le.o ext/mbstring/oniguruma/src/utf8.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/html_entities.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_7bit.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_ascii.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_base64.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_big5.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_byte2.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_byte4.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_cp1251.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_cp1252.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_cp1254.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_cp5022x.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_cp51932.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_cp850.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_cp866.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_cp932.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_cp936.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_gb18030.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_euc_cn.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_euc_jp.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_euc_jp_2004.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_euc_jp_win.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_euc_kr.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_euc_tw.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_htmlent.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_hz.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_iso2022_jp_ms.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_iso2022jp_2004.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_iso2022jp_mobile.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_iso2022_kr.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_iso8859_1.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_iso8859_10.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_iso8859_13.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_iso8859_14.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_iso8859_15.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_iso8859_16.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_iso8859_2.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_iso8859_3.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_iso8859_4.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_iso8859_5.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_iso8859_6.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_iso8859_7.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_iso8859_8.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_iso8859_9.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_jis.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_koi8r.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_armscii8.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_qprint.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_sjis.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_sjis_open.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_sjis_mobile.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_sjis_mac.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_sjis_2004.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_tl_jisx0201_jisx0208.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_ucs2.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_ucs4.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_uhc.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_utf16.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_utf32.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_utf7.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_utf7imap.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_utf8.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_utf8_mobile.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_uuencode.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_koi8u.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl/mbfilter.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl/mbfilter_8bit.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl/mbfilter_pass.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl/mbfilter_wchar.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl/mbfl_convert.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl/mbfl_encoding.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl/mbfl_filter_output.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl/mbfl_ident.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl/mbfl_language.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl/mbfl_memory_device.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl/mbfl_string.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl/mbfl_allocators.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/nls/nls_de.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/nls/nls_en.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/nls/nls_ja.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/nls/nls_kr.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/nls/nls_neutral.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/nls/nls_ru.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/nls/nls_uni.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/nls/nls_zh.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/nls/nls_hy.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/nls/nls_tr.o ext/mbstring/libmbfl/nls/nls_ua.o ext/mbstring/mbstring.o ext/mbstring/php_unicode.o ext/mbstring/mb_gpc.o ext/mbstring/php_mbregex.o ext/mysqli/mysqli.o ext/mysqli/mysqli_api.o ext/mysqli/mysqli_prop.o ext/mysqli/mysqli_nonapi.o ext/mysqli/mysqli_fe.o ext/mysqli/mysqli_report.o ext/mysqli/mysqli_driver.o ext/mysqli/mysqli_warning.o ext/mysqli/mysqli_exception.o ext/mysqli/mysqli_result_iterator.o ext/pdo/pdo.o ext/pdo/pdo_dbh.o ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.o ext/pdo/pdo_sql_parser.o ext/pdo/pdo_sqlstate.o ext/pdo_mysql/pdo_mysql.o ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_driver.o ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_statement.o ext/pdo_sqlite/pdo_sqlite.o ext/pdo_sqlite/sqlite_driver.o ext/pdo_sqlite/sqlite_statement.o ext/phar/util.o ext/phar/tar.o ext/phar/zip.o ext/phar/stream.o ext/phar/func_interceptors.o ext/phar/dirstream.o ext/phar/phar.o ext/phar/phar_object.o ext/phar/phar_path_check.o ext/posix/posix.o ext/reflection/php_reflection.o ext/session/mod_user_class.o ext/session/session.o ext/session/mod_files.o ext/session/mod_mm.o ext/session/mod_user.o ext/shmop/shmop.o ext/simplexml/simplexml.o ext/simplexml/sxe.o ext/soap/soap.o ext/soap/php_encoding.o ext/soap/php_http.o ext/soap/php_packet_soap.o ext/soap/php_schema.o ext/soap/php_sdl.o ext/soap/php_xml.o ext/sockets/sockets.o ext/sockets/multicast.o ext/sockets/conversions.o ext/sockets/sockaddr_conv.o ext/sockets/sendrecvmsg.o ext/spl/php_spl.o ext/spl/spl_functions.o ext/spl/spl_engine.o ext/spl/spl_iterators.o ext/spl/spl_array.o ext/spl/spl_directory.o ext/spl/spl_exceptions.o ext/spl/spl_observer.o ext/spl/spl_dllist.o ext/spl/spl_heap.o ext/spl/spl_fixedarray.o ext/standard/crypt_freesec.o ext/standard/crypt_blowfish.o ext/standard/crypt_sha512.o ext/standard/crypt_sha256.o ext/standard/php_crypt_r.o ext/standard/array.o ext/standard/base64.o ext/standard/basic_functions.o ext/standard/browscap.o ext/standard/crc32.o ext/standard/crypt.o ext/standard/cyr_convert.o ext/standard/datetime.o ext/standard/dir.o ext/standard/dl.o ext/standard/dns.o ext/standard/exec.o ext/standard/file.o ext/standard/filestat.o ext/standard/flock_compat.o ext/standard/formatted_print.o ext/standard/fsock.o ext/standard/head.o ext/standard/html.o ext/standard/image.o ext/standard/info.o ext/standard/iptc.o ext/standard/lcg.o ext/standard/link.o ext/standard/mail.o ext/standard/math.o ext/standard/md5.o ext/standard/metaphone.o ext/standard/microtime.o ext/standard/pack.o ext/standard/pageinfo.o ext/standard/quot_print.o ext/standard/rand.o ext/standard/mt_rand.o ext/standard/soundex.o ext/standard/string.o ext/standard/scanf.o ext/standard/syslog.o ext/standard/type.o ext/standard/uniqid.o ext/standard/url.o ext/standard/var.o ext/standard/versioning.o ext/standard/assert.o ext/standard/strnatcmp.o ext/standard/levenshtein.o ext/standard/incomplete_class.o ext/standard/url_scanner_ex.o ext/standard/ftp_fopen_wrapper.o ext/standard/http_fopen_wrapper.o ext/standard/php_fopen_wrapper.o ext/standard/credits.o ext/standard/css.o ext/standard/var_unserializer.o ext/standard/ftok.o ext/standard/sha1.o ext/standard/user_filters.o ext/standard/uuencode.o ext/standard/filters.o ext/standard/proc_open.o ext/standard/streamsfuncs.o ext/standard/http.o ext/standard/password.o ext/standard/random.o ext/tokenizer/tokenizer.o ext/tokenizer/tokenizer_data.o ext/wddx/wddx.o ext/xml/xml.o ext/xml/compat.o ext/xmlreader/php_xmlreader.o ext/xmlrpc/xmlrpc-epi-php.o ext/xmlrpc/libxmlrpc/base64.o ext/xmlrpc/libxmlrpc/simplestring.o ext/xmlrpc/libxmlrpc/xml_to_dandarpc.o ext/xmlrpc/libxmlrpc/xmlrpc_introspection.o ext/xmlrpc/libxmlrpc/encodings.o ext/xmlrpc/libxmlrpc/system_methods.o ext/xmlrpc/libxmlrpc/xml_to_xmlrpc.o ext/xmlrpc/libxmlrpc/queue.o ext/xmlrpc/libxmlrpc/xml_element.o ext/xmlrpc/libxmlrpc/xmlrpc.o ext/xmlrpc/libxmlrpc/xml_to_soap.o ext/xmlwriter/php_xmlwriter.o ext/xsl/php_xsl.o ext/xsl/xsltprocessor.o ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_connection.o ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_alloc.o ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_charset.o ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_wireprotocol.o ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_loaddata.o ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_reverse_api.o ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_vio.o ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_protocol_frame_codec.o ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_statistics.o ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_driver.o ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_ext_plugin.o ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_auth.o ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_result.o ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_result_meta.o ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_debug.o ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_commands.o ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_block_alloc.o ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_read_buffer.o ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_plugin.o ext/mysqlnd/php_mysqlnd.o ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_ps.o ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_ps_codec.o TSRM/TSRM.o TSRM/tsrm_strtok_r.o main/main.o main/snprintf.o main/spprintf.o main/php_sprintf.o main/fopen_wrappers.o main/alloca.o main/php_scandir.o main/php_ini.o main/SAPI.o main/rfc1867.o main/php_content_types.o main/strlcpy.o main/strlcat.o main/explicit_bzero.o main/mergesort.o main/reentrancy.o main/php_variables.o main/php_ticks.o main/network.o main/php_open_temporary_file.o main/output.o main/getopt.o main/streams/streams.o main/streams/cast.o main/streams/memory.o main/streams/filter.o main/streams/plain_wrapper.o main/streams/userspace.o main/streams/transports.o main/streams/xp_socket.o main/streams/mmap.o main/streams/glob_wrapper.o Zend/zend_language_parser.o Zend/zend_language_scanner.o Zend/zend_ini_parser.o Zend/zend_ini_scanner.o Zend/zend_alloc.o Zend/zend_compile.o Zend/zend_constants.o Zend/zend_dtrace.o Zend/zend_execute_API.o Zend/zend_highlight.o Zend/zend_llist.o Zend/zend_vm_opcodes.o Zend/zend_opcode.o Zend/zend_operators.o Zend/zend_ptr_stack.o Zend/zend_stack.o Zend/zend_variables.o Zend/zend.o Zend/zend_API.o Zend/zend_extensions.o Zend/zend_hash.o Zend/zend_list.o Zend/zend_builtin_functions.o Zend/zend_sprintf.o Zend/zend_ini.o Zend/zend_sort.o Zend/zend_multibyte.o Zend/zend_ts_hash.o Zend/zend_stream.o Zend/zend_iterators.o Zend/zend_interfaces.o Zend/zend_exceptions.o Zend/zend_strtod.o Zend/zend_gc.o Zend/zend_closures.o Zend/zend_float.o Zend/zend_string.o Zend/zend_signal.o Zend/zend_generators.o Zend/zend_virtual_cwd.o Zend/zend_ast.o Zend/zend_objects.o Zend/zend_object_handlers.o Zend/zend_objects_API.o Zend/zend_default_classes.o Zend/zend_inheritance.o Zend/zend_smart_str.o Zend/zend_execute.o main/internal_functions_cli.o sapi/cli/php_cli.o sapi/cli/php_http_parser.o sapi/cli/php_cli_server.o sapi/cli/ps_title.o sapi/cli/php_cli_process_title.o  -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lexslt -liconv -liconv -lintl -lpng -lz -ljpeg -lz -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lm -lxml2 -lz -licucore -lm -lcurl -lxml2 -lz -licucore -lm -lfreetype -lmysqlclient -lxml2 -lz -licucore -lm -lxml2 -lz -licucore -lm -lxml2 -lz -licucore -lm -lxml2 -lz -licucore -lm -lxml2 -lz -licucore -lm -lxml2 -lz -licucore -lm -lxml2 -lz -licucore -lm -lxslt -lxml2 -lz -licucore -lm  -o sapi/cli/php
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_res_9_dn_expand", referenced from:
      _php_parserr in dns.o
      _zif_dns_get_mx in dns.o
  "_res_9_dn_skipname", referenced from:
      _zif_dns_get_record in dns.o
      _zif_dns_get_mx in dns.o
  "_res_9_init", referenced from:
      _zif_dns_check_record in dns.o
      _zif_dns_get_record in dns.o
      _zif_dns_get_mx in dns.o
  "_res_9_search", referenced from:
      _zif_dns_check_record in dns.o
      _zif_dns_get_record in dns.o
      _zif_dns_get_mx in dns.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

I update my mac system from Mac sierra ， and my php-fpm can not startup. it seems some library path change, so I download a new source code , php-7.2.4 , Compiling the same way, but fail.

can anyone help me ?

Update:
I change the configure

```
./configure '--prefix=/Users/weizhao/lnmp/php-7.2.4' '--with-fpm-user=weizhao' '--with-fpm-group=weizhao' '--with-config-file-path=/Users/weizhao/lnmp/php-7.2.4/etc/php.ini' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/Users/weizhao/lnmp/php-7.2.4/etc' '--with-pdo-mysql' '--with-curl' '--with-pear' '--with-gd' '--with-jpeg-dir' '--with-png-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.34' '--with-zlib' '--with-freetype-dir' '--with-mhash' '--with-mysqli' '--enable-pdo' '--with-openssl' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-xsl' '--with-gettext' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-fpm' '--enable-opcache' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-wddx' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-exif' '--with-iconv' --with-libzip
```

It can make success, but a new error come out

```
/Users/weizhao/lnmp/php-7.2.4/bin/php -v
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
[1]    15923 abort      /Users/weizhao/lnmp/php-7.2.4/bin/php -v
```

*resolved:*

**I found my ~/.base_profile SET the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH a special path long time ago. then delete the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=xx , all things work.**

Comment: this question has nothing todo with PHP

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the command line tools

```
xcode-select --install
```

run that command in your mac Terminal

Comment: xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

Comment: softwareupdate --list   
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
No new software available.